# 'Error in chol.default(sigma.u) : the leading minor of order 1 is not positive definite'

Tags: r

the code that I put in R studio is:

```
# Load the necessary packages
library(vars)

# Define the matrix of data
data <- matrix(c(1.2, 0.8, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1), ncol = 3)
data
# Define the names of the variables
colnames(data) <- c("Industrial Production", "Financial Uncertainty", "Macro Uncertainty")
colnames(data)

colnames(model$data)

# Define the VAR model
model <- VAR(data, p = 1, type = "const")
model

# Execute the Cholesky-SVAR analysis
cholesky <- irf(model, impulse = "Financial.Uncertainty", response = c("Industrial.Production", "Macro.Uncertainty"), ortho = TRUE)

# Extract the data for the graph
plot_data <- plot(cholesky, plot.type = "single", ylabels = c("Industrial Production", "Financial Uncertainty", "Macro Uncertainty"), main = "Cholesky-SVAR: Responses to Government Expenditure Shock")

# Display the graph
plot(plot_data)
```

but R give me an error:

```
> cholesky <- irf(model, impulse = "Financial.Uncertainty", response = c("Industrial.Production", "Macro.Uncertainty"), ortho = TRUE)
Error in chol.default(sigma.u) : 
  the leading minor of order 1 is not positive definite
```

Can you help me?

I try to change the names of endogenous variables but I think that with the point ("Macro.Uncertainty"    "Industrial.Production"     "Financial.Uncertainty") it's ok. also the matrix I think it's ok.

I want a graphic where I can see how financial uncertainty influence macro uncertainty and industrial production, throught cholesky svars model

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/79450/87002 This is a potential reason: "The problem occurs because you have overfitted your model (too many parameters, variables), some variables are highly colinear or you have cases that have missings on all variables."